# Downloading all files in a FTP folder and then deleting them

Tags: c#, network-file-transfer

I've created two methods in a class that allow me to download  the contents of an FTP folder and if specified then delete them. Although the code operates as intended I think it's vastly bloated and I'm looking for direction on how to correct it.

Of note I believe that there's far too many FTP connections opened in a single file move (three I believe - list directory, download files, delete files). I'm a bit unsure how to refine this.

```
public void DownloadFolder(string localFilesPath, string remoteFTPPath, bool deleteAfterDownload = false)
{
    remoteFTPPath = "ftp://" + Hostname + remoteFTPPath;
    var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(remoteFTPPath);

    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
    request.Proxy = null;

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    List<string> directories = new List<string>();

    var line = reader.ReadLine();

    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    {
        directories.Add(line);
        line = reader.ReadLine();
    }
    reader.Close();

    using (var ftpClient = new WebClient())
    {
        ftpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);

        for (var i = 0; i <= directories.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (!directories[i].Contains("."))
            {
                continue;
            }

            var path = remoteFTPPath + "/" + directories[i].Remove(0, directories[i].IndexOf(@"/") + 1);
            var transferPath = localFilesPath + @"\" + directories[i].Replace(@"/", @"\");

            PostEvent($"Attempting to download File: {path} to: {transferPath}", Debug);

            try
            {
                ftpClient.DownloadFile(path, transferPath);
                PostEvent($"Downloaded File: {path} to: {transferPath}", Info);

                PostEvent($"Preparing to delete file: {path}\n\n", Debug);

                if (deleteAfterDownload)
                {
                    DeleteFile(path);
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                PostEvent($"Error downloading or deleting file {path} to {transferPath}", Error);
                PostEvent($"Exception: {ex.Message}", Error);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                PostEvent($"General Exception: {ex.Message}", Error);
            }
        }
    }

    response.Close();
}

public void DeleteFile(string remoteFTPPath)
{
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(remoteFTPPath);

    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
    request.Proxy = null;

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    PostEvent($"Deleting file {remoteFTPPath} returned status {response.StatusDescription}", Debug);

    response.Close();
}
```

Here's the class initializer (where my credentials are passed into properties within this class):

```
public FtpHelper(string ftpHostname, string ftpUsername, string ftpPassword)
{
    Hostname = ftpHostname;
    Username = ftpUsername;
    Password = ftpPassword;
}
```

And the `postevent` method that's referred to here come's from a base class I inherit to this class (unsure if this is bad practice, please let me know if so):

```
public class BaseHelper
{
    private EventHandler<BaseExceptionEventArgs> _onEvent;

    public event EventHandler<BaseExceptionEventArgs> OnEventHandler
    {
        add { _onEvent += value; }
        remove { _onEvent += value; }
    }

    /// <exception cref="Exception">A delegate callback throws an exception.</exception>
    public void PostEvent(string message, BaseExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionLevel exceptionLevel,
        Exception exception = null)
    {
        if (_onEvent == null) return;

        if (exception == null)
        {
            var e = new BaseExceptionEventArgs(message, exceptionLevel);
            _onEvent(this, e);
        }
        else
        {
            var e = new BaseExceptionEventArgs(message, exceptionLevel, exception);
            _onEvent(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing I would do is change your constructor:

```
private readonly NetworkCredential credentials;

public ftpHelper(string ftpHostname, string ftpUsername, string ftpPassword)
{
    credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
    Hostname = ftpHostname;
}
```

That eliminates newing up credentials all over your code.

As for the rest of your code, I think a few well named functions will make the code much more readable. For example, getting a list of files:

```
private IEnumerable<string> ListDirectories(string remoteFtpPath)
{
    var url = $"ftp://{Hostname}{remoteFtpPath}"; // Is this right? Not used C#6 yet...

    var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    request.Credentials = credentials;
    request.Proxy = null;
    
    var directories = new List<string>();
     
    using (var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            directories.Add(line); 
        }
    }
    return directories;
}
```

You could write the above using `yield` if you'd rather.

Go through your code and keep pulling out all of the methods aiming to get each one to do a single thing.

For example, I'd probably pull out another method from the above (`ListDirectories`) called `CreateListDirectoriesRequest` and have that create the `WebRequest`.

## Other thoughts

`Ftp` or `ftp` never `FTP` in names.

What you're doing with your `remoteFTPPath` parameter is very confusing. I'd have no idea what it was for a lot of your method.

It's easier to use `using` than calling `Close`/`Dispose` most of the time.

You almost certainly want to log `ex.ToString()` rather than just the message. You'll want the stack trace when you're tracking down problems.

Comment: Appreciated, will go through this once out of the office! And yes, string interpolation is amazing for easy to read syntax! Worth looking into!